# PHP Cookie not setting on Form Submit

Tags: php, forms, post, cookies

So here's the deal. I have a login form and I can set the cookie fine with Jquery but my employers want it done with php. So i've attempted to do so.

Here's my form

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['commit'])){
     echo "<a id='loginbtn' class='btn dropdown-toggle loginbtn' href='#' data-toggle='dropdown'>Sign in <strong class='caret'></strong></a>";
     echo "<div id='loggedout' class='dropdown-menu' style='padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;'>";
         echo "<form name='LoginForm' id='LoginForm' action=''  method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>";
             echo "<input id='user_username' style='margin-bottom: 15px; height:25px;' type='text' name='username' size='30' value='Username' />";
             echo "<input id='user_password' style='margin-bottom: 15px; height:25px;' type='password' name='password' size='30' value='********' />";
             echo "<input class='btn btn-primary' id='login' style='clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;' type='submit' name='commit' value='Sign In' />";
         echo "</form>";
     echo "</div>";
     }
?>
```

And when i try to set the cookie it looks like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['commit'])){
       $username= $_POST["username"];
       setcookie("TestCookie", $username, time()+3600, '/', 'mydomain.com');
    }
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class='wf-franklingothicurwcond-n5-active wf-franklingothicurwcond-n7-active wf-active' lang='en'>
```

I, at one point, made the $username variable global and output it on the page so i know that that is working but for some reason the cookie will not set.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:

Don't know if it makes any difference but I am using Bootstrap as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are set as part of the HTTP header and can't be set successfully if there is any other output sent to the browser first. So is there any whitespace or other text/html content above the php tag in your cookie page? If so, remove it and try again.

I'd suggest making a separate minimal test case with just the cookie stuff in it first of all, then once you are confident you have that working, add your post logic.

Comment: That fixed it Thank you :) I had a function above where I was setting the cookie :P

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are setting it correctly in PHP using the `setcookie()` method. My first guess would be the possible difference between the server and local time.

Perhaps this cookie is expiring as soon as it is set because you and the server are located in different timezones? Look at [setting a timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and the [list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Again, from the code sample and explanation, this is just a guess. It also could be that your browser is not set to accept cookies, etc...

Hope that helps.